# Wall full of post and comment in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, web

I have a problem with my small website service. I have to code some Wall with the post and comment from user.
I have some model for Post:

```
 public class Post
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PostContent { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostDateTime { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

and for Comment:

```
  public class Comment
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CommentContent { get; set; }
    public DateTime CommentDateTime { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
}
```

How could I display all Posts and his comment in the view?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When I need to mix up things coming from different models, I use a [ViewModel](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3) usually.

It's a model made for specific views where I put data from various sources or particular computations.

Basically it's just another model, with the fields needed.

In your case it could be something like

```
  public class PostAndComments
{
    public int IDPost { get; set; }
    public int IDComment { get; set; }
    public string CommentContent { get; set; }
    public DateTime CommentDateTime { get; set; }
    public string PostContent { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostDateTime { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
}
```

And in your action you will pass both a Post and a Comment model, assing to PostAndComment the various fields from both and pass that to the View.

The action should be something like

```
ActionResult PostComment(Post post, Comment comment)
{
    PostAndComments postcomment = new PostAndComments
        {
            IDPost = post.ID,
            IDComment = comment.ID,
            etc... etc...
        }
}
```

Making it throught a partial view would add unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Ok, but how display all Post + comment on one page? How it could be look like? How it's look like in controller?

Comment: Ok, i will try that :D

Comment: @Zarobiek Once you're in the cshtml page, in which you have passed a

model PostAndComments

You can just write you html page with separate divs for posts and comments (or just take a template somewhere) and easily call

Model.PostContent and Model.CommentContent where you need

Note that all these code calls will need a @ in front of them so Razor engine will call them as C# code

Comment: It's doesn't work :/ I have that PostComment, but when i call that in views by @Model.PostContent i don't display anything :/ I have just null in any filed of object PostComment in controller

Comment: I should see some code to check what's going on... The reason why the model is null could be a lot. I use ViewModel often and if anything is done correctly everything goes fine. Try to debug the action and check if the Post and Comment that you pass to it are null too in first place

Comment: It seems to be null when i create them. PostAndComments postcomment = new PostAndComments{ ... }. For example post.ID is null etc

Comment: Post post and Comment comment is just null. So how i could do this?

Comment: @Zarobiek It means you're passing them null to the action. You must search when you call that action and populate them before passing them to the action. It's like calling a method and passing null objects to him. They will be null when the method will use them.

Comment: Hooray for the retards of the Q&A police closing another useful question.

Comment: can u post some Action where populate some object and send them to that action that u post?